How to use Theme.of(context) to add color to labelTextStyle
In the general ThemeData of my flutter app, I have the following code to give a general style to the NavigationBar.
This is the way to style the label under the icon within NavigationBarTheme, based on the doc.
In the class that handles the Navigation, so elsewhere in the app, I need to add color property to the TextStyle, maintaining the other properties via Theme.of(context).
But how can I do this with WidgetStateProperty.all?
Thanks in advance!
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      navigationBarTheme: NavigationBarThemeData(
        labelTextStyle: WidgetStateProperty.all(
          const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}


TextStyle(....,color?

@Md. Yeasin Sheikh the theme is general at the beginning of the app, and I need to set color elsewhere in the app, then using Theme.of(context).copyWith, but I don't know how to do it with WidgetStateProperty.all

do you want to add a new property to ThemeData or what?

@pskink yes, I want to add color to TextStyle inside labelTextStyle

if you want to add a new property to ThemeData then why are you using NavigationBarThemeData?

@pskink I need to style the label under the icon inside the NavigationBarTheme, and this is the way to do it based on the doc

and why do you mention Theme.of then? Theme.of returns ThemeData, not NavigationBarTheme

@pskink because NavigationBarTheme is a property of ThemeData. What should I do then?

ah ok, i did not know it is a property of ThemeData - use MaterialStateProperty.all then

well I might be missing something but if you like to override theme a specific widgetTree(layout) you can wrap with Theme and provide data/override there

@pskink MaterialStateProperty was deprecated after version 3.19, WidgetStateProperty is the new property and works the same way. But how can I extend the theme within it?

@Md. Yeasin Sheikh this overrides the other properties inside TextStyle, if I'm not mistaken

@pskink in my installation labelTextStyle is of type WidgetStateProperty<TextStyle?>?.
However, the problem is the same: I don't know how to override a single property inside it, keeping all the others intact

@pskink MaterialStateProperty is defined as a type alias for WidgetStateProperty the moment they deprecated it. Analyzer knows it's an alias that's why the actual type is shown as the type for the labelTextStyle property on IDE

You can resolve the WidgetStateProperty for all the possible states (since you're applying the same style to every states anyway) to get the underlying TextStyle and use copyWith on that resolved value.
final theme = Theme.of(context);

final navigationBarTheme = theme.navigationBarTheme;

// Resolve the WidgetStateProperty for all possible states to get the underlying TextStyle
final labelTextStyle = navigationBarTheme.labelTextStyle!.resolve({...WidgetState.values})!;

final newTheme = theme.copyWith(
  navigationBarTheme: navigationBarTheme.copyWith(
    labelTextStyle: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
      labelTextStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.green),
    ),
  ),
);


You can also make extension methods to help with these tasks:
extension WidgetStatePropertyX<T> on WidgetStateProperty<T> {
  T resolveAll() => resolve({...WidgetState.values});

  WidgetStatePropertyAll<T> copyAll(T Function(T) transformer) {
    final newValue = transformer(resolveAll());
    return WidgetStatePropertyAll(newValue);
  }
}

And the usage is now much simpler:
final theme = Theme.of(context);

final navigationBarTheme = theme.navigationBarTheme;

final newTheme = theme.copyWith(
  navigationBarTheme: navigationBarTheme.copyWith(
    labelTextStyle: navigationBarTheme.labelTextStyle!
        .copyAll((textStyle) => (textStyle!.copyWith(color: Colors.green))),
  ),
);


Do you mean doing something like this??
MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(color: Colors.white))


this way the other font properties declared in the main ThemeData are overridden

Huh?  what is your scenario, aren't you just trying to change a specific property on a widget at the local level, thus overriding the default theme? If so just set the color property there and it will override the theme entry for that single property and nothing else.
